# jQuery Mobile: Taps won't register with `vclick` or `touchend`

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this mobile touch indicator, but in Chrome's mobile emulator, how come taps only get registered using `mouseup` but not `touchend or`vclick` (http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)?

With `vclick` (taps don't register): http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/LnhrF/14/embedded/result/

With `mouseup` (taps register): http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/LnhrF/9/embedded/result/

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function () {
    $('button').on('vclick', function (event) {
        showActionIndicator(event, event.pageX - 30, event.pageY - 30);
    });

    function showActionIndicator(event, pageX, pageY) {
        var touchIndicator = $("#touchIndicatorDiv");

        touchIndicator.html($("#touchIndicatorTemplate").html());

        touchIndicator.css("left", pageX);
        touchIndicator.css("top", pageY);

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: `vclick` is a custom event, it ignores other bubbled events such as `mouse` events.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `touchend` won't work either.

Comment: `touchend` works http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LnhrF/15/

Comment: I'm afraid not - it doesn't seem to register - otherwise you'd see the `You clicked the button!` message.

Comment: i'm not binding it to show a msg, just to console.log.

Comment: Thanks! So to finalize things: 1) Despite on `mouseup` working on desktop, it's always best to use on `touchend` if this is a specific mobile feature right? 2) I simplified things a little -- http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/LnhrF/22/ -- but had to remove the `event.preventDefault` to be able to follow links after the animation displaying. May I have your blessing?

Comment: Why would one want `event.preventDefault` in this thing in the first place? Is it ok that I took it out?